# Customize Joomla 3.7 search : searchareas by default

Tags: php, joomla3.7

I would like to customize Joomla 3.7 search (default area checked = SP page, Jevents pages unchecked).

See screenshot

Thanks for your help

[What I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxQHs.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do an override:
Copy the file `"modules\mod_search\tmpl\default.php"` into the folder `"templates\YOUR_TEMPLATE\html\mod_search\"` and modify it as you like.